# need high camera fps

Tags: camera, pi-zero-w

Could you suggest a camera for raspberry with high fps - about 100 frame rates and HD resolution?

I found 5MP OV5647 with CSI interface but it is HD 60fps and 640*480 90fps. Also, I would like to use RPi Zero W. Does it applicable to record high fps video to sd card?
Or possibly is there some other boards to make something like action camera with additional sensors?

Thank you in advance.
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by a RaspiCam version 2 and a Raspberry pi Zero. Take a look at this table:

[image: Version 2.x (IMX219)]

*[More about this table](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md)*

As you can see, it can reach up to 200fps on 640*480 resolution. Also, with the RaspiCam version 1, it reaches 90fps on the sale resolution.

---

***References:***

1. [Raspberry Pi Camera Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md)
   This document describes the use of the four Raspberry Pi camera applications.
2. [v2 camera raspivid now captures up to 200fps](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=206047)
   A lot of sources, details, tests, and experiences.
3. [PiCamera increase FPS on raspberry pi zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=236776#p1447662)
   Make sure that you can do it by Raspberry Pi Zero.